# Free variables, bound variables and quantification - explanation

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

I'm trying to learn something about mathematical logic. I think, I partly understand definitions of free variables, bound variables and quantification, but it's not easy topic for me and it's not enough to solve problems. I mean, for example I have such problem:

mark sets on a graph:

- $\{ z : \mathbb{R} | \forall{x}\exists{x}(x=1) \}$
- $\{ z : \mathbb{R} | \exists{x}\forall{x}(x=1) \}$
- $\{ x : \mathbb{R} | \exists{x}\forall{x}(x=1) \}$

What is $z$ in this case? How to think about such problems? How to solve them?

I'm not asking You to solve that particular problem; I want You to explain me (or give some links to articles, tutorials, books etc.) this topic (free variables,bound variables and quantification).

I would really appreciate You help.

Comment: The three bulleted expressions don't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

[These](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs103a/handouts/18%20Intro%20to%20Quantification.pdf) (Stanford notes on quantification) notes seem good.

Comment: Link is dead. May be better to place authors, title etc.